# Element is not clickable at (1215/912). Other element will receive the click. This code works well in FirefoxDriver but doesn't work in ChromeDriver

Tags: jquery, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
//driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
//driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
baseUrl = "http://www.cargiant.co.uk/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl + "/default.asp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div[2]/p")).click(); //**this element can't be clicked**
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[title=\"Value my car\"]")).click();
```

I am using selenium webdriver. I am able to run the above code successfully on FirefoxDriver but unable to run it successfully on ChromeDriver and IEDrver. When i use chromedriver it gives an exception Element is not clickable at point (1215, 912). Other element would receive the click

Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Probably because it's further down the page. Try scrolling.

Comment: put some wait. Could be an issue with element loading

Comment: @Arran. I think this might be the issue. I noticed it doesn't scroll all the way down to where the element is during test run. I have tried everything else still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The below code works in Chrome (**And, if run in FF with necessary code changes, still it works!!**):

```
WebDriver driver;
String baseUrl;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.cargiant.co.uk";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/default.asp");

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div[2]/p"))).click().build().perform();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("img[title=\"Value my car\"]")));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[title=\"Value my car\"]")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make a simple change in your xpath.
Try using

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div[1]/p")).click();
```

instead of

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[5]/div[2]/p")).click();
```

Comment: That works fine but I get stuck in the driver.switchTo().frame(myFrame); when using chromedriver